# React Table default pagination page

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm new to react-table. Is it possible to set default page in the pagination mode. Is there a certain prop to handle this? F.ex. after my component mounts I'd like to have my table opened on 5th page. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably already discovered this, but to expand on hariharan's answer, you can use the state of a component to control a lot of the props of the table. For the page, you can tell the component that the page is found in the state,

```
<ReactTable
    ...otherProps
    page={this.state.page}
  />
```

And when you initialize your state, however you initialize it, have page equal to 5. For example,

```
class MyClassThatHasReactTableInIt extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page: 5
  }
... // etc code etc
```

If you do this, you also need to handle the page changing yourself though. *luckily*, react-table makes this very easy, you can write your custom pageChange handler:

```
    <ReactTable
    ...otherProps
    page={this.state.page}
    onPageChange={page => this.setState({page})}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `page` prop in `<ReactTable />` component

```
  <ReactTable
    ...otherProps
    page={5}
  />
```

Just change `5` to the page number that you want.

Comment: if you just add page number. pagination will not work. this needs to be handled.

Comment: @thakurinbox But he asked to display the nth page in the initial render. handling page change was not in the scope of the question